# how i put my virtualhost online (wamp 3.2.3)

Tags: php, virtualhost

In this version of wampserver the option "put online" is no longer available, I made a php application with a virtualhost and I would like to put it online or locally on the company's wifi box.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

1 .To put your website in your LAN, u need to know your device's LAN ip address. open your command line and use this command to get your local ip address:

```
ifconfig
```

then find your php.ini file to get your apache service port, glue the ip address and port, others in your LAN can visit your website. like: 192.168.1.110:8080

2.to put your website online, there is a whole bunch of stuff u need to learn. please find a article or book, it's hard to explain that in a short reply

Comment: when you say connect to the LAN you say the same wifi or with wire RJ45?

Comment: @AnthonyMARTIN yes, lan mean local area network